# Is it possible to playback arcore with 60 fps?

Tags: android, arcore

I found this official example of ArCore implementation

https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hello_ar_java

And as far as I understood ArCore can make playback only in 30fps

But I did not find official definitions about it. Like

> ArCore restricted to playback max in 30fps...

So, is it correct? Or I can playback in 60fps?

**EDIT**

Also I found this

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/camera-configs

And according to this settings

```
ArCameraConfigFilter_setTargetFps(AR_CAMERA_CONFIG_TARGET_FPS_30);
```

I think we can say that 30fps is a max speed

Comment: What makes you think you cannot? Checking sources you can find flag: AR_CAMERA_CONFIG_TARGET_FPS_60 although as written, only supported on some devices. ArCore supports 60FPS capture rate from August last year, cannot say if this includes playback

Comment: @Myszsoda ok, but I checked google example (link above) with time measuring, and I get `OnDrawFrame()` callback call with 30 fps speed...

Comment: Are you sure your device supports 60Hz refresh rate and your device is on 60 FPS supported list for ArCore?